# Django polls: NoReverseMatch with chartit

Tags: html, django, django-templates, bar-chart

I am using chartit in Django and I want to integrate it on my polls application. I can display the graph by typing complete URL like http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/chart/. But if I want to access using a button on the html page I get this NoReverseMatch error. What I have to do here to get it working?

My url.py has

```
url(r'^chart/$', views.model_property, name='column_chart'),
```

views.py

```
def model_property(request):
ballot = Ballot.objects.all()[0]
ds = DataPool(
        series=[{
            'options': {
                'source': ballot.contestants.all(),
            },
            'terms': [
                'contestant_name',
                'votes'
            ]
        }]
)

cht = Chart(
        datasource=ds,
        series_options=[{
            'options': {
                'type': 'column',
                'stacking': False,
                'stack': 0,
            },
            'terms': {
                'contestant_name': [
                    'votes'
                ]
            }},
        ],
        chart_options={
            'title': {
                'text': 'Ballot statistics'
            },
            'xAxis': {
                'title': {
                    'text': 'Contestants'
                }
            }
        }
)
# end_code
return render_to_response('polls/graph.html',
                          {
                            'chart_list': cht,
                            'title': "Test Chart"})
```

From html I have a boostrap button using which I would like to access this link

```
    <a href="{% url 'polls:chart'  %}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{% bootstrap_icon "glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" %} </button>
    </a>
```

Chart looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is error using url namespace in the anchor tag.

Change your :

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:chart'  %}">
```

to

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:column_chart'  %}">
```